XPresent in a user application that is run with compositing manager
I have an interactive graphics application that run with X11 server. Graphics output can be produced with a means of software rendering(update pixel buffer with a CPU), as well as by the means of OpenGL.
Most X11 desktop systems run a compositing manager these days. So I choose to create pixel buffer manually, suppling output to X11 server with xcb_put_image. Now I want a better control syncing with a monitor refresh.
My thoughts are to use XPresent extension to X11 protocol. The strategy is to reduce power usage. I want to:
1. get an event that signals that compositing manager, 
   or X11 server has finished syncing with a monitor scanout.
2. do some computations and update pixel buffer.
3. submit pixel buffer to the X server
4. wait/sleep until next event

The question
If I supply the pixel buffer with a XPresentPixmap function, will it play nicely with a compositing manager? I mean is it OK for user application to use this function? Will I get proper Notify events?
Maybe there is a modern way to get notifications from X11/compositing manger about image presentation with regards to monitor update?
For now I use blocking epoll that handles all events/X11 messages/signals and such. I prefer to stay with epoll.
